# Replying to a private message as a Facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, message, facebook-page

I created a tool for our support team that gets all private messages from our +/- 70 Facebook fan pages for easy processing and not having to manually click through all the pages to check if there are new or unanswered messages.

This tool worked perfectly for a couple of months but recently we've been getting the following error when trying to send a reply on a private message:

```
[error] => Array
(
    [message] => (#504) Invalid reply thread id
    [type] => OAuthException
    [code] => 504
)
```

My code is as follows:

```
    $fb->setAccessToken('%access_token%');
    $edge = 't_id.' . $thread['id'] . '/messages';

    $result = $fb->api($edge, 'POST', array('message' => $message));
```

I use extended access tokens but just to be sure I renewed them all. The value in `$thread['id']` is the value from 'thread_id' from querying FQL 'message' table.

I searched in the Facebook docs but it looks like they removed everything concerning this subject, which could imply they removed the functionality entirely.

They say something about a new messages system which they are rolling out on the thread reference page, but I can't find anything else about this subject. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/

EDIT:
As you can see in the comments the documentation can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations

I just made a new page for testing and I can't seem to get a valid access token in the graph api exlorer for accessing the edge `/{page-id}/conversations`. I remember this has happened before when I was developing my tool. The same access tokens didn't work for a week and then  suddenly started working again...

Comment: Have you tried using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/conversations instead?

Comment: Hmmm, so thats where the documentation went... But still looks like as if the call is correct

Comment: did you solve this issue? I have the same problem and can't find anything

Comment: Nope. But I'm goin to F8 so i'll try to get an answer there... ;)